# How can i do length check of x on sub-domain of email id

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Email**- foobar@pakamat.co.in **Username** - foobar **Domain** - pakamat.co.in

Accepted:

foobar@cool.com
foobar@co.cool

Rejected:

foobar@c.com
foobar@cool.c

need each sub-domain of email to be of alteast 2 characters long and subdomains cannot start or end with a hyphen, nor have two in a row. Below is regex for handling hyphen condition but facing problem with having atleast 2 characters in subdomain

```
var emailIdExp = /^[\w-_\.]+@\w+(-\w+)*(\.\w+(-\w+)*)+$/
```

Comment: You can refer : http://emailregex.com/

Comment: Don't know exactly what you want but as per example given by you, this regex should be useful.
var regEx = /.+@\w{2,}\.\w{2,4}/

Answer (score 0):

try this regex.

```
/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
```

UserName is `\1`   or   `$1`
Domain is  `\5`     or      `$5`

Answer (score 0):

`^.*?@(\w{2,}\.)+\w{2,}$` will work for you.

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/vzkgbE/1)

Answer (score 0):

Other answers didn't address all of your requirements, especially that *subdomains cannot start or end with a hyphen, nor have two in a row.* I used the subpattern `\w(-?\w)+` for this.

```js
m = ["foobar@cool.com", "foobar@co.cool", "foobar@c.com", "foobar@cool.c"];
emailIdExp = /^\w+@(\w(-?\w)+\.)+\w\w+$/;
console.log("Accepted:");
for (k in m) if (m[k].match(emailIdExp)) console.log(m[k]);
console.log("Rejected:");
for (k in m) if (!m[k].match(emailIdExp)) console.log(m[k]);
```